# How can assign posting to Subscriber to specific category?

Tags: categories

I'd like to permit posting(writing) to "Subscriber"group to a specific category.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

**[Bind user to category](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bind-user-to-cat/)**

This plugin allows you to restrict users to only posting in specfic categories.

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is a specific "group(role)", not "users" can post to a specific "category" . for example, who has "Subscriber" role, he can post "QnA" category. Sorry for my poor english.